# Access denied snowsql via asp.net application

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have asp.net web application. User can upload excel data, then convert to text file. After that run snowsql to load text data to DB. I got the error.

Access is denied: 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.snowsql

I have done other server it is working fine. New server got above issue. Please advise.

Comment: Just as a side note: make sure the user you connect to Snowflake with has _only_ the minimum necessary to run the PUT statement to a named internal stage. That way if there's a maliciously crafted Excel file that allows injection the damage it can do is limited.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few potential issues here, but short version it appears that somehow either the default location for the config files (%USERPROFILE%.snowsql) is being evaluated incorrectly or you're setting the config parameter to SnowSQL. It shouldn't be trying to access system32 (and you *definitely* shouldn't give it permission to try!).

I'd recommend explicitly setting the --config parameter when you call out to SnowSQL and letting us know how that goes.

Otherwise, it might be useful if you can supply the line of code that's failing as well as any relevant context.